# How can I create a file with StreamWriter using a relative path?

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, prism

When I run the following code, an XML file is **correctly created** in `c:\temp`:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Models.Customer>));
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("C:/temp/CustomerMock2.xml"))
{
    xs.Serialize(wr, CustomerList);
}
```

**However**, I actually want it to be created in a **sub-directory** underneath the project, but when I do this:

```
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("Data/CustomerMock2.xml"))
```

it just acts as if it writes it but the file **never appears** in that directory:

`C:\Projects\Prototype12\CustomersModul\bin\Debug\Data`.

**How can I create a file with StreamWriter with a relative path inside my project?**

Comment: this is a WPF application using Prism, so this is taking place in a module

Answer (score 9):

It is always dangerous to rely on the 'Current Directory' concept, so you will need a starting point. In a WinForms project, you can get the location of the .EXE with

```
string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

In WPF there will be something similar.

But if you are in a library and do not have access to the Application (or Environment) objects, you should consider making a BaseFolder parameter or property to let the main application take control over folders.

Answer (score 5):

Does `./Data/CustomerMock2.xml` work?

```
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("./Data/CustomerMock2.xml"))
```

Comment: This _does_ seem to work, however where `.` will put you is seemingly application dependent. I was working on a plugin for another application, and `.` defaulted to the file the app was working with, so it ended up in `Documents` (I was just logging an error, so this was fine). Depending on what you're doing, working out where exactly you are would be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Are you setting the XML data to be copied at compile time (so it's not in the actual project directory, but the bin folder)? In which case you can get to it using

```
string xmlFile = string.Format("{0}/Data/{1}",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"myxml.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are relative to the current directory. Maybe you're not in the bin/debug directory... You should build the absolute path based on the exe directory, as shown by Chris.
Also, the StreamWriter constructor won't create the directory, you need to create it explicitly if it doesn't exist.